# PCM input to pocketsphinx

Tags: pocketsphinx

Is it possible to directly feed a pcm data to pocketsphinx instead of first converting it into a wav file? If yes then please help me with the code in c.

PS: The pcm input is coming fron a analog device, like a microphone interfaced with arduino which then forwards the sampled pcm data to a linux machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is provided in [tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx) and in continuous.c in sources in more advanced version:

```
ps_start_utt(ps);
utt_started = FALSE
while ((k = fread(adbuf, sizeof(int16), 2048, rawfd)) > 0) {
    ps_process_raw(ps, adbuf, k, FALSE, FALSE);
    in_speech = ps_get_in_speech(ps);
    if (in_speech && !utt_started) {
        utt_started = TRUE;
    }
    if (!in_speech && utt_started) {
        ps_end_utt(ps);
        hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, NULL);    
        ps_start_utt(ps);
        utt_started = FALSE;
    }
}
ps_end_utt(ps);
```

The main call is `ps_process_raw` which takes a data buffer.